# Zend Many to Many Relationship

Tags: database, zend-framework, many-to-many

I want to retrieve all the data from 3 tables

users , properties and users_properties.

So I decided I would use the manytomanyRowset. But to my surprise I get the data from the properties and users_properties table but no data from the users table. Why is that? I need some columns from the users table is there a way to tell the manytomanyrowset function that I need the data from the current table as well?

this is my function

```
public function fetchRegisteredProperties()
{

    $userTable = $this->getTable();
    require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/DbTable/UsersPropertiesDB.php';
    require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/models/DbTable/PropertiesDB.php';

    $propertiesRowset = $table->fetchAll();
    $allProperties = array();

    foreach ($propertiesRowset as $row) {
        $propertiesRowset = $row->findManyToManyRowset(
          'Model_DbTable_Properties','Model_DbTable_UsersProperties');
        $allProperties = array_merge($tempArray,$propertiesRowset->toArray()); 
    }

    return $allProperties;
}
```

thanks in adavance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I designed and coded the table-relationships features in Zend Framework.

The answer to your question is no, the `findManyToManyRowset()` method only fetches rows from the related table, it does not merge them into the corresponding Row object.  The reason is that a Row object in ZF can `save()` itself back to the database, and if you add fields it won't know what to do with them.

So you should implement a custom Row object to hold both user fields and the collection of user properties -- store the user properties as a Rowset object.

Then extend `__get()` and `__set()` so that it knows how to map fields into the correct array when you read or write object properties.  That is, if one tries to read or write a field that isn't part of the user row, it falls back to the user properties Rowset.

Also extend `save()` to save not only the current row, but also call `save()` on the Rowset of user properties.

Comment: oh ok cool makes sense. I'm new to zend framework and I was used to the ways cakePhp handles things. Thanks for your quick response!