# Zend Table relations saving / updating

Tags: zend-framework, save, sql-update, zend-db-table, table-relationships

Currently I'm working on a cms page module where I need to update pages after made some modifications on for instance the text. Because I'm getting multiple data from several tables, I also need to save / update the data to multiple tables.

Updating data to one particular table isnt a problem, but for some reason I cant figure out how to do the same trick with table relationships. One of my questions is how to do this and if you maybe need to create a single savePage method for every model and handle the particular data seperately. Or is their a better solution to handle the saving with options like ManyToManyRowsets.

I'm not sure if its me searching for the wrong thing or if the thing I want, just doesnt excist. Anyway, the following link seems to look a little like what I want. If someone could help me out, I would be very thanksfull.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/640648/1553963

Answer (score 0):

this post should answer your question (there is no easy way) and provide you with an how to too:

[Zend Many to Many Relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036450/zend-many-to-many-relationship)

Lucian